# User Defined Function in Awk

Tags: shell, awk

I am facing as issue in below mentioned call to User Defined function using AWK

```
awk '{
     if ("${PROS}" == "" )
                       wq_fm_exception ${FILE_SEQ_NBR}
                       #exit 1
                       HEAD="TRUE"

}
```

where wq_fm_exception is a user defined function being written in same script in which awk is being called. The parameter name ${FILE_SEQ_NBR} passed to function wq_fm_exception is defined globally.

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: awk is not shell. It is a completely different tool with it's own language. Shell just calls awk to perform tasks, just like shell can call a C program to perform tasks. You cannot access shell functions or variables inside awk just like you cannot access them within C programs. If you tell us what you are trying to do with sample input and expected output then we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

AWK cannot call functions defined in the spawning shell. You could, however, have it write its error to a file and exit with failure, and have the spawning shell then deal with that:

```
if ! awk '{
    if(...) {
        print "can't frobnicate the bar" > "/tmp/errors"
        exit 1
    }
}'; then
    wq_fm_exception "$(cat /tmp/errors)"
    exit $?
fi
```

(If you choose to go with this method, you’d probably want to use `mktemp` to generate a filename for `/tmp/errors` rather than hardcoding it.)

Comment: i have some statements written in my function. and i need to call this function depending of success/failure of if statement. isnt there any way to call this function from within awk?

Comment: @rahulgulati: No, you cannot do it directly. The best you can do is have AWK indicate somehow to the shell that you want *it* to run the function—whether that’s through a signal, a pipe, an exit status… but AWK can’t run your shell function. That’s the shell’s job.

Comment: @rahulgulati: you're not being clear. you can declare functions in `awk`. Is your function an `awk` function or a shell function. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter its a shell function and i want to call that shell function in between awk. Thant function takes one parameter as well.  Please suggest

Comment: if you only want to pass parameters and not expect any return value, you'll have to turn your shell function into a shell script file (maybe with a function inside), and then call your function like `cmd ="/path/to/script/with/function/wq_fm_exception " file_seq_num ; cmd ; close(cmd);`